# Mobile and Desktop responsive markup

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and I am using bootstrap framework. I want the website to be responsive for most the divices. The thing is that the mobile markup is a kind different form the desktop markup, not all the markup but some blocks. What shoould I do? Reapeat the information and show and hide depending on the device? What is the best practice?
Thanks in advance!

For example I have this markup that show the same information but have different structure, this is just an example:

```
<div class="mobile-show desktop-hide">
<span>Here is my product list</span>
 <ul>
  <li>Item number 1</li>
  <li>Item number 2<li> 
</ul>
<div>


<div class="desktop-show mobile-hide">
 <h1>Here is my product list</h1>
 <div class="icon-block">
   <img src="icon1"></img>
   <img src="icon2"></img>
 </div>
</div>
```

By the media queries I show and hide depending the device, my fear is that I am duplicating the information because it is show in a different structure html, I dont know is that is correct.

Comment: Use server side code for content that is shared.  And just include that content regardless of which template you use.  That way you can have two totally different templates for desktop/mobile, and still have your content in one place.

Comment: I am using media queries to show and hide html blocks, but not sure if this is a good choice. I also have block with the same information but with different markup for mobile and for desktop, what should I do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever defines that block should be local to that template and that template alone.  When I say "content", I mean just that.  There should be no markup other than P tags, or typical HTML styling.

Comment: For example I have an information to show but the html is different in mobile than desktop, so I will have one html block for mobile and other for desktop, but both 'versions' show the same information. Is that a good practice?

Comment: All I'm saying is that if the styling is different for that HTML block - like the div uses a different class - then you are correct to have that defined in the template.  Whatever that HTML content is should be made to work in either template.  Meaning, you have your fonts, sizes, etc, defined in the template already.  Your HTML should behave and react accordingly.

Comment: In your example, your HTML content is completely different.  There is no reason for that.  You shouldn't be using a DIV block on one device, and an UL block on another.  That makes no sense.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I said was an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have duplicate elements doing the same thing - just assign different classes to each of the elements and display them differently on screen sizes. Bare in mind that some classes dont show up on smaller screen sizes - e.g. `col-lg` and `col-md`.

```
<div class="mobile col-lg-8 col-xs-8">
<span>Here is my product list</span>
 <ul>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"><img class="show">Item number 1</li>
  <li class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6"><img class="show">Item number 2<li> 
</ul>
</div>

.show {
display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
.show {
display:block;
}
}
```